# Weight of Diamagnetic Objects in Lenz Effect

Tags: electromagnetism, kinematics, lenz-law

I've seen the simple experiment of dropping a neodymium sphere down through a copper or aluminum tube where it falls at less than ***g***. The "Lenz Effect"

My question is:

Has there ever been an experiment when the NeoD sphere is tied to a string attached to a weight scale? Does the sphere weigh less at the midpoint inside of the tube than it does moving outside of it?

---

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have done such an experiment, but it would be messy. It would be a lot easier to measure how long it takes the magnet to fall through the tube to get the same result.

*Assuming* the magnet falls with a *uniform* acceleration, since $$y=\frac{1}{2}at^2 \\
\rightarrow a=\frac{2y}{t^2}$$ Since you know the length of the tube $y$, and if you measure the time the magnet takes to fall through the tube $t$, then you can calculate the net acceleration of the magnet.

From this you can calculate the (net) force applied on the magnet, which is simply $$F_N=ma=\frac{2my}{t^2}$$ where $m$ is its mass. This force will obviously be smaller than the magnet's weight force.

Comment: Thank you, Joseph. That equation would also apply if a stream of air was suspending the sphere as well. I am more curious about the diamagnetic source than I am about the symptom though.

It has the lingering scent of quantum locking and it seems as if that magnetic sphere were rotating at a certain velocity, it could hold it's position (If torque helped as well...as it must I suppose). Now that would **not** be a messy experiment!